# Access 2007 - Alternative to the Ribbon menu

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, menubar

I've recently discovered that custom menus were "Replaced" (That's what MSDN says) by the ribbon system.

I find this rather silly when multiple-form access databases rarely have use for common menu functionality, which I feel the global scope of the ribbon is good for (I guess).  I mean I actually like the Ribbon for the office 2007 products, but I have no desire to use it for my database gui.

I'm tempted to just put a dozen small buttons on my form...

Does any body have any alternatives/ideas you like to use as opposed to this.. failure on Microsoft's part.

I just need to make a simple gui for for some basic new/edit/delete records, go to forms, some custom actions, etc.

sigh, a menu would be so nice.

Comment: Just to be clear, you do not want custom ribbons (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2062091/how-do-i-switch-between-access-form-and-datasheet-views-and-remain-on-the-same-r/2064325#2064325) ?

Comment: I agree 100% with the main point here -- Ribbons are great for Office applications, but not for custom Access apps, which have a much more limited set of functions, so don't need the architecture of the ribbon to expose hidden functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could hide the Ribbon by creating a custom one with minimal functionality, and then use macros to create some menus. 
Customize the Ribbon: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/customize-the-ribbon-HA010211415.aspx
Create menus via macros: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/create-custom-menus-and-shortcut-menus-by-using-macros-HA010282509.aspx

-Steven Thomas